# Help finding SNMP ODI's for Windows

Tags: windows, snmp

I am setting up some monitoring on some Windows infrastructure and am having problem locating the ODI's that I am after.  Effectively what I need are the ODI's for the following

1) % of CPU utilisation (either used or free).

2) Disk Free

3) % of Free Memory (or bytes)

I am doing my testing on XP but will be deploying to 2003/2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your SNMP agent will implement the [host MIB](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2790.html), and that contains the relevant disk/cpu information. The data is structured in quite a complex fashion, and often the easiest way to find what you want is simply to browse through with a MIB browser.

Comment: Processor load is available on .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2 which is the percentage of free processor time.

Comment: Storage size (includes RAM, Virtual RAM and HDD) is available on .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.5.

Comment: Used storage is available on .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6